# Does requiring NPS/satisfaction score to give feedback skew results?

Tags: user-research, feedback, nps

The other day I wanted to leave feedback on my gym's website. The feedback widget looks like this:

[image: Feedback widget with How Satisfied Are You scale]

The first question is a mandatory satisfaction score (I clicked 10, but it's not the default).

I would have preferred to skip the satisfaction question because I wasn't in the mood to quantify my overall experience, I just wanted to send the feedback.

But, since it's mandatory - wouldn't users have a tendency to either give a very high rating or a very low rating to make sure their feedback is prioritized, regardless of whether they're "feeling the feelings", so to speak? And wouldn't that defeat the purpose of measuring satisfaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this could differ across type of businesses* (putting a caveat on this generalization here), I have tested a similar consideration in the past by creating two different versions (randomized, as a sort of A/B test).
One with the sat. item optional, and one with the sat. item as mandatory.

**This did not result in a significant difference** for me (and based on my sample size I believe the power was sufficient for this to be a valid in not rejecting the H0 hypothesis).

---

Given both versions had sat. results that came from 'surveys' piggybacking user initiated feedback (as I believe from your description is your example as well) it would be interesting to test these against standalone survey results initiated from the website/app side (unrequested by the user), mostly because this is a more conventional* sampling method for this type of sat. measurement.

*  *The organization I tested this for was not for a gym or sports business*
*  *Easier to generate large sample sizes as you don't have to wait for a user to be pro-active, and perhaps fewer potential sampling biases by not selecting only those that have experienced a bug or other factors that can affect the impulse to give feedback*